# Access a variable inside a method through App.get_running_app().root (Kivy)

Tags: python, variables, methods, kivy

I'm trying to access variables that are inside another method. However, I am getting an error.

I'm creating TextInput, according to the number the user passes, and then when the user fills in that TextInput, I want to take the text written by the user and use it for a specific purpose after the button is pressed. I'm trying to do this through App.get_running_app().root.something

Python code:

```
import sys, os, pyautogui
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.resources import resource_add_path
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MeuLayout(ScrollView):
    def criar_pessoa(self, numero):
        if numero.isnumeric():
            if int(numero) > 20:
                pyautogui.alert('Excedeu o valor limite!')
            else:
                i=1
                nome = []
                sobrenome = []
                email = []
                telefone = []
                while i < int(numero)+1:
                    self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text= f'Nome da {i}° pessoa:', size_hint_y= None, height= 100))
                    self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text=f'Sobrenome da {i}° pessoa:', size_hint_y=None, height=100))

                    nome_pessoa = TextInput(write_tab= False, multiline=False, size_hint_y=None, height=30)
                    self.ids.grid.add_widget(nome_pessoa)
                    nome.append(nome_pessoa)


                    sobrenome_pessoa = TextInput(write_tab= False, multiline=False, size_hint_y=None, height=30)
                    self.ids.grid.add_widget(sobrenome_pessoa)
                    sobrenome.append(sobrenome_pessoa)


                    self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text=f'Email da {i}° pessoa:', size_hint_y=None, height=100))
                    self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text=f'Telefone da {i}° pessoa:', size_hint_y=None, height=100))

                    email_pessoa = TextInput(write_tab= False, multiline=False, size_hint_y=None, height=30)
                    self.ids.grid.add_widget(TextInput(write_tab= False,multiline=False, size_hint_y=None, height=30))
                    email.append(email_pessoa)

                    telefone_pessoa = TextInput(write_tab= False, multiline=False, size_hint_y=None, height=30)
                    self.ids.grid.add_widget(TextInput(write_tab= False,multiline=False, size_hint_y=None, height=30))
                    telefone.append(telefone_pessoa)

                    i += 1
                    if i - 1 == int(numero):
                        pass
                    else:
                        self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text='_'*60, size_hint_y=None, height=100))
                        self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text='_'*60, size_hint_y=None, height=100))

                    if i-1 == int(numero):
                        self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text='', size_hint_y=None, height=100))
                        botao = Button(text='Iniciar', size_hint_y= None, height= 50, on_release = self.enviar)
                        self.ids.grid.add_widget(botao)

        else:
            pyautogui.alert('Coloque apenas números!')
        self.ids.numero_pessoas.text = ''

    def enviar(self, widget):
        n = App.get_running_app().root.criar_pessoa.nome[0].text
        print(n)

class AppCadastro(App):
    def build(self):
        return MeuLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        resource_add_path(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS))
    AppCadastro().run()
```

Kivy code:

```
<MeuLayout>
    scroll_wheel_distance:80
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        id: grid
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

        Label:
            text: 'Seu email:'
            font_size: 17
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 100
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'left'
            anchor_y: 'center'
            TextInput:
                id: email
                write_tab: False
                multiline: False
                size_hint_x: None
                width: 300
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30

        Label:
            text: 'Sua senha:'
            font_size: 18
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 100
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'left'
            anchor_y: 'center'
            TextInput:
                id: senha
                write_tab: False
                multiline: False
                password: True
                size_hint_x: None
                width: 300
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30



        Label:
            text : 'Quantidade de pessoas: (limite: 20)'
            font_size: 18
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 100
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'left'
            TextInput:
                id: numero_pessoas
                write_tab: False
                multiline: False
                size_hint: .1, .1
                size_hint: None, None
                height: 30
                width: 30
                on_text_validate: root.criar_pessoa(numero_pessoas.text)

        Label:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 100
        Label:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 100
```

Error:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'nome'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access a variable like `nome` in your `criar_pessoa()` method because it is a local variable (local to that method) and is discarded as soon as the method completes. If you want to access `nome`, you need to change it into a type of variable that will be maintained after the method completes. One way to do this is to make it and instance variable of the `MeuLayout` class. Simply change every occurrence of the `nome` variable to `self.nome`, them replace:

```
def enviar(self, widget):
    n = App.get_running_app().root.criar_pessoa.nome[0].text
    print(n)
```

with:

```
def enviar(self, widget):
    n = App.get_running_app().root.nome[0].text
    print(n)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It worked out! If I could, I would give you an up arrow.